# Duplicate Events from Jquery when loading partials views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, events, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have table with a button per row each button can get the same partialview with diferent objets same model, and I insert the html into a Div, the partialview have a Jquery on click event.

Something like this

```
<div id="MyDiv">
</div>
<script>
funtion InserthtmlToDiv(){
//data (partialView html) from ajax
$('#MyDiv').html(data);
}
</script>
```

PartialViewCode

```
<div>
My html
<button  type="button" id="MyButton">ShowAlert</button>
</div>
<script>
$('#MyButton').on("click", function (e) {
    alert('@Model.ID');
});
</script>
```

Each time I get a partial view the event on click of MyButton is like "saved" even replacing the html of MyDiv, so when I click on the button I can get N numbers of alerts per loaded partialViews.

I can solve if replacing the event with a funciton, but how can I prevent from save the events and just execute the one in the inserted div.

Notes:
I have multiple events with the same problem like this, this is an example.
I only have one button with the Id="MyButton".
The div "MyDiv" is not in the partial view, every time the partial view is loaded, the event listener of "MyDiv" adds the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your click event is inside partial view, it will every time bind click event.
so in your case just add your click event in main Page, where your table is rendered.

1. You can give same class to each rows button, and create one common click event for all button.
2. Give attr value with unique value to each button so in click event you can identify, where to load partial view.
3. Just follow below steps.

```
     <script>
        $('.myButton').on('click',function(){
         var clickedButton = $(this).attr('data-id');
         // Add your code 

    });
     </script>
```

Comment: Mybutton is on the rendered partialview, is not the button from the table, I know I can add to the main page,but what I want to prevent the bind click event additon when rendered the partial view when I use on click (or whatever event) of the partial view

Comment: I got your point, you do not need to move button from partial view to main page, you just need to add your click event code in main page. if you prevent the bind click event, then how you perform your operation?